# What happens if a voltage is applied to the gate of a MOSFET when both drain and source are shorted?

Tags: mosfet, nmos, pmos

- Can this damage P- or N-type MOSFETs? Does this affect gate current absorption?

A side question:

- Instead of connecting D and S together and letting them float, what if they are both tied to ground, or both tied to a power supply?

Comment: what else is connected?  if the gate is isolated from this shorted drainsource there is nowhere for current to actually flow.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you stay within the rated voltage limits, there is no problem shorting drain and source. All you're doing is shorting out the channel resistance. Gate current is a function of Vgs/Vgd, but in most applications it will be negligible. The device is useful in this configuration as a capacitor.

For your second question, the capacitance will be a function of the (shorted) s/d voltage. You can make use of this property to digitally trim a capacitance. By driving digital trim bits into the s/d of weighted FETs configured this way, you can alter the total capacitance (to small-signal ground) on some node.